# Dump in MySQL Workbench, unknown database

Tags: mysql, database, export, dump, workbench

Im trying to dump going: Server>Data Import> Import from self-contained file> then select my dump.sql>start import and getting the error:

> 21:54:55 Restoring C:\Users\jonpr\Desktop\loja_cliente.sql
>
> Running: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump.exe" --defaults-file="c:\users\jonpr\appdata\local\temp\tmpoaygw1.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments  < "C:\Users\jonpr\Desktop\loja_cliente.sql"
>
> mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database '<' when selecting the database
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 2
>
> 21:54:55 Import of C:\Users\jonpr\Desktop\loja_cliente.sql has finished with 1 errors

I tried put this code in very top and didnt worked.

```
create database if not exists `loja` ;
use `loja`;`
```

My dump file right know:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.24, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: loja
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.24

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,         FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `cliente`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cliente`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `cliente` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `cpf` char(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sexo` enum('m','f') DEFAULT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nascimento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cliente`
--

LOCK TABLES `cliente` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cliente` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `cliente` VALUES (1,'jon','10609053612','m','rua             n','31986473597','1993-08-14'),(2,'vanessa','10609053613','f','rua         m','31321337','1992-06-21');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cliente` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2019-02-08 18:49:51
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after hours of search, i found the solution,  Import runs if `"Preferences->Administration->Path to mysql Tool"` is empty .

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different, unrelated problem, and it's likely something else fixed your problem (which I'm also having with Workbench, which I'm quickly finding is an unintuitive piece of junk). For the record, that field in Preferences was empty by default on my installation (i.e. from a fresh install).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out to backup a specific database.

Replace `db1` with the name of the database you want to backup:

```
mysqldump -u username -p db1 --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > db1-backup-$(date +%F).sql
```

Comment: Sry, i dont get it at all i think, i tryied it in workbench: mysqldump -u username -p loja --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > loja-backup-$(date +%F).sql and didnt work

Comment: Hey you need to pass the above command in your terminal /mysql>  not the workbench.